# How to create a directory in C# *only* if it doesn't already exist?

Tags: c#, windows, io

Directory.CreateDirectory creates a folder if it doesn't already exist, otherwise it just returns the DirectoryInfo for the already-existing folder.

But I want to make sure I create a new sub-folder every time a process is run  (run1, run2, run3, etc).  And multiple people may be running that process at once.  So I can't do

```
if (!Directory.exists("run77"){CreateDirectory("run77");}
```

Because that has a race condition - someone else may create the folder in between those two calls.

Is there any way to ensure that I definitely get the next unused folder name?

Comment: Why? If you make it while someone else allready did or not make it while someone else allready did, the result would be the same in either cases

Comment: Probably best not to use sequential numbers unless you have some sort of synchronised service that will give you the next available number. Why not use a GUID for the folder name instead?

Comment: _"And multiple people may be running that process at once"_ - so, include the PID in the name?

Comment: @Wouter: Well, if you try creating a working directory for yourself and might get back one that another process created for itself, the result is definitely different.

Comment: This method is flawed from the start. You will have to either use something with a low collision rate (like GUIDs) or a synchronized source of incremental integers. Or, if it's just a working directory, and each user is only running one instance at a time, just put it somewhere in the user's home dir.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious answer: Don't use sequential IDs in this case. Use GUIDs instead. For things happening in multiple instances at once I rarely found sequential numbers helpful in that there isn't really an inherent *sequence*.

The other option would be to drop down to [the Windows API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa363855(v=vs.85).aspx) where you can just try and re-try creating directories with increasing sequence numbers until the call succeeds, at which point you found your directory to work with.

Comment: Creating a directory is also atomic. The problem is there is no atomic check-if-exists+create, nor is there an atomic check-if-exists+rename.

Comment: I agree, but your whole second paragraph is based on renames being atomic, which is irrelevant. The rename has the exact same problems as the create that OP is doing already.

Comment: @Adrian: Just noticed that there's no rename for directories anyway, and MoveTo wouldn't do what I want. I removed that option altogether. GUIDs would be my favourite here anyway :)

Comment: Yeah, the frustrating thing here is that the Win32 API does exactly what I want (fails if I try to create a folder that exists), and the code inside Directory.CreateDirectory() goes to a lot of effort to work around that!
It'll have to be GUIDs instead.

Comment: Got it.  I _can_ create a file in that folder that's locked.  Use _that_ as a mutex, and that way any other processes that come along will know to create a new folder.

Comment: Unless you're hellbent on looking like a Unix application I'd probably just use a mutex instead of a lock file. There's no particular good reason on Windows to put a mutex in the file system, except you're working in a language that supports practically nothing, such as batch files.

Comment: Mutexes don't work across multiple machines.
I've got multiple users kicking off runs of the application on their machine, putting the results in a central location, and I want to keep the sets of results separate.  A folder for each result set is the best option there, and I can either give each one a GUID (horrible UX), make the users create a folder themselves (horrible UX) or create a reasonably named folder, put the results there, and then tell them where to find it (nicest UX I can think of).

Answer (score 2):

This goes way beyond merely creating directories. You have multiple processes (on multiple machines even, maybe) that want to obtain a sequentially named resources, for themselves only.

If you definitely want to do this, you will have to synchronize it yourself. So either:

- If the processes run on the same machine, use a machine-wide lock (e.g. Mutex) that synchronizes the directory creation code.
- Create an out-of-process central authority (other than the filesystem itself) which provides the next number upon each successive, synchronized call.
- Create a sentinel file / lock file containing a process-specific value, during the presence of which no other processes will try to create a directory, and remove it after creating the directory.
- Apply filesystem permissions in such a way, that attempting to *write into* the given directory raises an error (if `CreateDirectory()` doesn't throw already). Then you'll have to assume that any permission error means a race condition occurred, and try to create the next directory.

All of those are brittle solutions.

Comment: May be worth mentioning that the mutex option would fail if the solution was ever scaled up to multiple machines writing to a network share. Probably not an issue for OP, but you never know...

Comment: There are many other issues to consider if you are going beyond a single machine.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to introduce a simple synchronization using exclusively opened file.

Here is possible implementation (as not fully thought code):

```
FileStream lock = null;
try
{
    // someUniequeLockFileName - should be the same for all processes and unlikely to match real name in that folder
    lock = File.Open(Path.Combine(currentFolder, someUniqueLockFileName), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
    ... // you successfully obtain lock, can create subfolders
}
catch { }
finally
{
    lock.Close();
}
```

Comment: This would just throw an exception if something else has it locked, a fairly expensive operation.

Comment: @DavidG, exception vs IO operation, really? But ok, it's not the fastest solution.

Comment: Yes, exception would be very expensive here because you would need to put this in a loop while waiting for the file to become available. Better to use one of the other methods mentioned or maybe a mutex (assuming this is only running on a single machine).

Comment: @DavidG, good point, I've used something similar to simply tell other user to retry attempt some time later where only few people trying to do it simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

One way is using a `mutex` which is an expensive call.  However like most said if possible use sequential Ids instead.  Here is an example using a `mutex`:

```
Mutex m = null
try
{
    m = new Mutex(false, "CreateDirectoryMutex");
    m.WaitOne();
    if (!Directory.exists("run77"))
        CreateDirectory("run77");
}
finally
{
     if(m != null)
       m.ReleaseMutex();
 }
```

Comment: A mutex isn't going to help, they're talking about separate processes running concurrently.

Comment: If you are using a named `mutex`, it can be used over many processes if they are using the same name.

Comment: @Adrian A mutex is system wide so it would work just fine

Comment: Ah, did not realize named mutexes were system-wide. @DavidG unnamed mutexes only apply to the current process, which is what I'm used to using.

Comment: Like @DavidG said, `mutex` is system wide and `critical section` is per process.

Comment: @Adrian Funny, I've never used unnamed mutexes :)